# Change last element in a Path using a Rewrite Rule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to create a Redirect using a Rewrite rule, which rewrites the path "**/page-2**" into "**?start=1**". For example:

```
http://mysite/article/page-2
```

Needs to be changed to:

```
http://mysite/article?start=1
```

Trying with:

```
RewriteRule */page-2$ ?start=1 [R=301,L]
```

Seems not to work. Any help ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^article/page-2/?$ /article/?start=1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

#### [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)